# Append index.html to all requests that are a directory with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a nginx rule that will append `/index.html` to all directory requests for the `/static` endpoint. For example, requests `http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/test` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/test/` would be redirected to `http://10.0.0.1:3000/static/test/index.html`, but file requests like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/style.css` would be redirected to `http://10.0.0.1:3000/static/style.css`. My current approach is to check  check if the `request_uri` is a directory or file and create the appropriate `proxy_pass` config, but I know that I am approaching this the wrong way. Below is my current config.

```
location ~ ^/static(.*)$ {
   if(-e $request_uri !~ \.) {
      proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:3000/static/$1/index.html;
   } 
   if(-e $request_uri ~ \.) {
      proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:3000/static/$1;
   }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this that actually works?

Comment: Does nginx have access to the static files? I think that you want to use `root /data/www/someproject/static; try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;` which will fallback to the index.html when the file is not found.  I believe you should use proxy_pass to redirect to another server, or backend-api or similar, but not a simple static frontend. (I'm not making an answer here, because this might be only be my opinion, but I strongly believe this is the norm.)

Comment: I should update my question, I used 127.0.0.1 as an example, but all the files live on a separate server than ngix so I would need to proxy_pass to get to that other server for both cases.